# Reading from Socket to String

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader

I'm trying to read from Socket's InputStream to a String variable, and then printing it. But, somehow, that doesn't work properly. `receivedText` is only printed to console when the client is disconnected. What's wrong with my code?

```
public xClient(Socket socket)
{
    Thread receiver = new Thread(){
        public void run()
        {
            String receivedText = "";
            while(socket.isConnected())
            {
                try {
                    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    String line;
                    while((line = input.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        receivedText += line;
                    }
                    if(!receivedText.equals(""))
                    {
                        System.out.println(receivedText);
                        receivedText = "";
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    receiver.start();
}
```

main method:

```
    ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket();
    socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1",9200));

    Thread accepting = new Thread(){
        public void run()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                try {
                    Socket received = socket.accept();
                    new xClient(received);
                    System.out.println("OK");
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    accepting.start();
```

Comment: But how does it suppose to work? You start a serversocket and then await for connection on the server and then you create a client that should create a connection in a first place? Do you initiate connection to the server from some other client or telnet?

Comment: xClient class was made for listening clients that were connected to server. It's not a class of a client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code..

```
 while((line = input.readLine()) != null)
 {
        receivedText += line;
 }
```

The readLine() function waits until it gets an input line or an indication that its end of the stream. You are checking it against null in the loop. It will reply null only when it gets an end of stream or in your case when the client is disconnected. The client should reply/write a last message informing end of file before disconnecting (or performing other action).

Comment: Thanks, now I got the problem but I have no idea about solving it. I'm completely new into sockets and threads. Can you give some advice?

Comment: EJP is right about the structure of the function. If you are done with the transferring then just close the stream at the client side. Here the readLine() will reply with null and the function will complete its job. If you still want to keep the connection, you got to send/receive a special text (like a flag) indicating that there will not be any more data sent after this.

Answer (score 0):

The readLine() method only returns null when the peer disconnects. If you want to print every line, do that inside the reading loop.

There are other problems:

- The 'while socket.isConnected()' test is pointless. It is connected and it will stay connected. The connection doesn't magically become false when the peer disconnects. You're already testing for end of stream when you read. You don't need another loop around that.
- Creating a new BufferedReader every time around that outer loop wouldn't work anyway: it would just cause data loss
- The sleeps in the reading and accept loops are also completely pointless.

Comment: I've added sleeps to give some time to CPU. Can you explain why it is pointless? Btw, where should I create BufferedReader?

Comment: 1. It is pointless because accept() will block anyway while there is no incoming connection, and readLine() will block anyway when there is no data. 2. Just remove the outer 'while' loop.